# How to ensure non null columns in Java (spring)

Tags: java, spring

I have a project (in Java and Angular) about designing a financial website to manage some data like contracts. In our databases, some columns can't be null.

In SQL for example, it's very easy to set that condition, and for that example, I have to respect that rules :

```
 ID NUMBER NOT NULL ,
 USER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
 PARENT_ID VARCHAR2(280) NULL,
 PARENT_LEGAL_NAME VARCHAR2(280) NULL  ,
 POLICY_BUCODE VARCHAR2(280) NOT NULL,
 POLICY_ID VARCHAR2(280) NOT NULL,
 POLICY_TYPE_CODE VARCHAR2(280) NOT  NULL  ,
 POLICY_ACTIVE_STATUS  NUMBER(1),
 POLICY_LEGAL_NAME VARCHAR2(280) NOT  NULL  ,
 PA_FLAG NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT  NULL   ,
 RISK_FLAG NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT  NULL   ,
 CC_FLAG NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT  NULL   ,
 VISIBLE_FLAG NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT  NULL
```

The problem is that I had to ensure that in java-side... and I had a lot of difficulty to fix that.

The idea for that is that if we read a Contract object from an array of Contract objects (like when someone want to enter new data in a table in SQL), we will check for that. So, if we are reading an array of contacts and a contract doesn't have a required field (for example POLICY_BUCODE), we will just skip it and jump to the next element. We can do that easily with a for loop.

The problem is that I got lost in the long code and I don't how to find those variables... For example, a Contract object has an ID which is an object of a class called ID!!!! Which I found very strange and I got very confused about that... I found also strange that some classes has name with underscore (ex : Coreinfo_.java)

So, I tried to do something like that :

```
 for (contract in contractList) {
 if (contract.getId() == null || contract.getId().getId() == null || contract.getId().getBuCode == null) {
     //don't do anything, just jump to the next element
 } else {
     //the rest of other codes
 }
```

The problem is that I'm not good enough in Java and I REALLY got lost in that long code. With my example, I "think" that i'm ensuring non null values for ID, POLICY_ID and POLICY_BYCODE but i'm not sure at all...

Here is my plunker with some of our java classes : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/BylPPjXLJ7PY0aBP5xPF

Can you just give me a little help to do that? at least by understanding the model and where are those variables located?

Comment: What ORM solution are you using with this - Hibernate or something you're putting together?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I had to ensure that in java-side... and I had a
>   lot of difficulty to fix that.

**You can set the constraints/rules even in Java classes like how you did in your SQL.**

For setting the constraints on Java class variables, you need to use `javax.validation.constraints` package rules.

For your `Contract` class `@NotNull` can be set on `id` variable as shown below :

```
public class Contract {

   @NotNull
   private long id;

   //other variables
}
```

You can apply various constraints like `@Min`, `@Max`, etc.. as well and you can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) for more details.